# Custom yml to spring boot application with application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to add my own custom.yml file under resources folder and read the config from it, where I already have application.properties and appInfo.properties files.

When I run the application it throws

```
Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'some.list'  
 Property: some.list.myList
    Value: null
    MyList: must not be null
```

But when I change custom.yml to custom.properties then it works well.

Below is my MainApplication class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:/appInfo.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:/custom.yml"})
})
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication, args);
    }
}
```

Below is my config class

```
@Validated
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.list")
public class CustomConfig {

    @NotNull
    private List<String> myList;

}
```

src/main/resources/custom.yml

```
some:
  list:
    my-list:
      - "value 1"
      - "value 2"
```

src/main/resources/application.properties

```
server.port=8070
#. other configs
 .
 .
```

src/main/resources/appInfo.properties

```
info.build.name=@project.name@
info.build.version=@project.version@-@rpm.release@
```

`Spring boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE with Java version 8`

Any lead will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you can try changing ".yaml" to ".yml". Because I haven't really seen ".yaml" file in Spring configuration. Also, in the documentation, I think it is mentioned as ".yml"

Comment: @MensurQulami tried with yml, still getting the same exception.

Comment: and what if you write `myList` instead of `my-list` in your yaml file ?

Comment: @Imaguest yes doesn't affect at all, after changing from myList to my-list

Comment: The `@PropertySource` is for loading property files NOT yaml files. SO this won't work. Instead of property sources (for both files) start the application with `spring.config.additional-location=classpath:/appInfo.properties,classpath:/custom.yml`. However I would strongly suggest using a single `application.properties` or `application.yml`.